HP 2000 windows 8 internet connection trouble
I am trying to update it. As of right now I have activated it and have it connected but says it's not connected to the internet.

You can't neither activate a Windows release many years out of support - unless you have a machine with the Windows key already saved in the firmware - nor update it.

"but says it's not connected to the internet." - So, activate it through phone activation process.

Windows 8 support has ended 2023. One reasonable approach to handle this could be installing linux.

Linux runs on old HP 2000 machines. It supports WiFi, and even the CD/DVD drive. One HP 2000 machine, I've switched to Ubuntu because Windows was far too slow.
